# What is the proper way to set MDC for logging in grpc-java with ServerInterceptor?

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

I want to use ThreadContext from log4j2 for setting MDC context keys like `request-id`, `user-id` to trace request information in logs for debugging.

I have written an `MdcInterceptor` which does the following:

```java
public class MdcInterceptor implements ServerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public <ReqT, RespT> ServerCall.Listener<ReqT> interceptCall(ServerCall<ReqT, RespT> call, Metadata headers,
                                                                 ServerCallHandler<ReqT, RespT> next) {
        ThreadContext.put("rid", generateId());
        return next.startCall(call, headers);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work as it seems that different callbacks may be called from different threads from Server executor with different `ThreadContext`s.

I've found some solution posted here https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1949#issuecomment-226884288 that says that `ThreadContext` should be set in every callback in `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener`.

The fact is that in my case some additional information should be added if possible in different `UserInfoInterceptor` which is called after `MdcInterceptor` (some auth user info which requires token validation and etc.). How should I add this information to request-scoped `ThreadContext` properly?

Is the posted solution the only possible variant? It looks little strange that I put try-finally block around each super-call in `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` not to mention that I should set context not once but in each callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [io.grpc.Context](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/v1.21.0/context/src/main/java/io/grpc/Context.java#L98), which handles the propagation of RPC specific information into your callbacks.   Before calling any of the events on your `ClientCall.Listener` (and `StreamObserver`), the gRPC library will install the correct context.  Ray Tsang has made a [good example](https://github.com/saturnism/grpc-java-by-example/blob/master/metadata-context-example/src/main/java/com/example/grpc/server/TraceIdServerInterceptor.java) of how to use the API.

Comment: Using `org.apache.logging.log4j.ThreadContext` I may not worry about logging messages if I define my PatternLayout like `%m %X{request-id}` because logging framework substitute `%X{request-id}` with value of the `key=request-id` from `ThreadContext`. With io.grpc.Context there will not be auto-substitution in log messages, will it?

Comment: You would need to install the result of `generateId` in the gRPC Context.    In your interceptor, you can read out of the gRPC, and temporarily put it into the ThreadContext.  (and remove it after you have intercepted each onMessage)

Comment: Could you tell me when should I _install the result of generateId in gRPC Context_? I can't see end-to-end chain of working with logging `ThreadContext`.
> remove it after you have intercepted each onMessage
Do mean I should create `ForwardingServerCallListener` and override `#onMessage` where I need to unset `ThreadContext`?

Comment: To be more clear I don't understand the following:
1. What are exact places where I have to set the `ThreadContext` to pass the value of `request-id` in every log message of my request? Should I create `SimpleForwardingServerCallListener` like in the example from github and set it in every callback?
2. Where I have to clear `ThreadContext`?
3. If I want `ThreadContext` to add some info in the middle of the request's flow (e.g. after authentication) how I may to update existing `ThreadContext`?
I've used _grpc.Context_ but have the problem that next request sees old `ThreadContext`.

Comment: You need to install it on each callback defined in the ClientCall.Listener (which SimpleForwardingServerCallListener is an implemenation of).   Install it to the io.grpc.Context in onHeaders(), and set the thread local before calling the delegate listener.  Remove it after you have called it.   In the other methods(like onMessage), read the requestId from the io.grpcContext and install it in the ThreadContext.   Remove it at the end of the callback.

Comment: I made a working example here: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/pull/5835

Comment: I suppose you mean not `ClientCall.Listener` but `ServerCall.Listener`. One more problem that next interceptors that has something to log won't be able to have `request-id` in log-lines because `ThreadContext` is not set for them. I've left the similar comment in your PR, thank you very much for your help!